# How to update in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data, persistence

I saw many questions about Core Data updates. Actually I am creating a simple application contact list app. It contains add, edit, delete and update functionalities. Here my update code. It works and updates, but it updates all the contact list. I need to update specific contacts only.

```
- (IBAction)updatePressed:(id)sender 
{
    delegate = [[AppDelegate alloc]init];
    delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    name2 = emailtxt1.text;
    email2 = nametext1.text;
    mobile2 = numbertxt1.text;
    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dict setObject:nametext1.text forKey:@"NAME"];
    [dict setObject:emailtxt1.text forKey:@"EMAIL"];
    [dict setObject:numbertxt1.text forKey:@"MOBILE"];
    [delegate UpdateDiary:dict];
}

- (void)UpdateDiary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSLog(@"update book Details Function Entered");

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Diary"inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSArray *mutableFetchResult = [[[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy] autorelease];

    if (mutableFetchResult == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Fetch result error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    for (Diary *ob2 in mutableFetchResult) 
    {
        {
        ob2.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"NAME"];
        ob2.email=[dictionary objectForKey:@"EMAIL"];
        ob2.phone=[dictionary objectForKey:@"MOBILE"];
        }
    }

    if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {               
        if([error localizedDescription] != nil)
        {           
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a predicate on your fetch request. That's how it knows which object(s) you want, rather than just fetching them all.

You could do something like:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email == %@", anEmailAddress];
```

If you did that, then the result of executing the fetch request would just be objects that matched the email address you set in the predicate.

Note, of course, that if there is more than one object with the same email address, then the fetch request would fetch all of them.

A better design for your app might be, when you go into the edit form, keep around the Core Data object that you're editing, possibly in a property on your view controller. (You'll have it around at that point I reckon, since you'll need to know what to populate the fields with.) That way you don't need to perform a fetch at the time the user is trying to commit the edit — you can just use the object you've kept around.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)UpdateBook:(NSMutableDictionary *)dictionary
    {


     NSLog(@"update book Details Function Entered");



     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];


     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Book"inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookID = %@", [dictionary objectForKey:@"vID"]];

     NSArray *mutableFetchResult = [[[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error] mutableCopy] autorelease];

     if (mutableFetchResult == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Fetch result error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

    for (Book *ob2 in mutableFetchResult) 
    {

        {

            ob2.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"VName1"];
            ob2.author=[dictionary objectForKey:@"VAuthor1"];
            ob2.discription=[dictionary objectForKey:@"VDiscription1"];
            ob2.bookID=[dictionary objectForKey:@"vID"];

        }
    }

    if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])
    {               
        if([error localizedDescription] != nil)
        {           
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..